# C# Generics and Reflection

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection

i'm using linq. All my queries looks like `var query = dc.GetTable<myType>()`.

I wish i could choose "myType" using a string parameter. I tried to create a Type object using reflection, but the compiler doesn't recognize Type objects as class definitions.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There's a [GetTable(Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310460.aspx) extension method which does exactly what you are looking for:

```
var query = dc.GetTable(Type.GetType("namespace.type, assembly"));
```

Comment: It's a good aproach, but I'm designing an application in three layers. All of them use generic logic. I would like to customize the class of work by using text strings in the presentation layer, and that information is spreading to the persistence layer.
Thanks

Comment: @dalbornoz - Your persistence layer needs to know what table to load the data from. You can't avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want that ?
Using the generic method like you do now, gives you compile time checking support, whereas a string parameter not.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an query instance as a generic Table<> object, but it won't be recognized in compile time. see [Using Type objects as Type Parameters for Generics in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467063/using-type-objects-as-type-parameters-for-generics-in-c)