# c# Type object to Type Paramater

Tags: c#, types

How can I use a Type object as a Type argument?

For example:

```
byte[] Data;
Type objectType;
public T MyFunction<T>()
{
     return OtherClass.Deserialize <objectType> (Data);
}
```

In other words, how do you use a Type object in a Type parameter `<typehere>`?

Comment: try <Type> instead of <myType>

Comment: I'm storing the type in a variable @FacioRatio

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1467119/961113)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics is really designed to work with types which are known at compile-time on the calling side. (The type argument can itself be a type parameter as far as the caller is concerned, of course.)

Otherwise, you're stuck with generics - you'd get the `MethodInfo` associated with `OtherClass.Deserialize`, call [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) using `objectType` as an argument, and then call the resulting method.

```
var method = typeof(OtherClass).GetMethod("Deserialize");
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(objectType);
object result = genericMethod.Invoke(null, Data);
```

Note that this won't return a `T` though. It's not clear why your `MyFunction` method is generic if you're not actually going to use the type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your generic method expects *type identifier* which is known at *compile time*. Meanwhile, you're trying to pass an *instance* of such a type to your method, but such an instance is not known until *runtime*.

Use reflection instead:

```
var method = typeof (OtherClass).GetMethods()
                                .Single(x => "Deserialize".Equals(x.Name) 
                                              && x.IsGenericMethodDefinition);
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { objectType });
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { Data });
```

Comment: How would you suggest doing it? Perhaps I was unclear, I guess the real question is how to cast an object to a type stored in a Type variable?

Answer (score 0):

Like this (recursively, for brevity):

```
Type myType;
public void MyFunction<T>(T instance) {
  MyFunction<Type>(myType);
}
```

Comment: This won't exactly work, I need to return a T type, not a Type object.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: Get an object of type myType from a `object` object, sorry, struggling to be clear here.

Answer (score 0):

here `myType` is a `Type` object. So you should call `MyFunction<Type>( myType);`

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're saying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should write MyFunction method like:

```
public T MyFunction<T>(byte[] data)
{
     return OtherClass.Deserialize<T>(data);
}
```

and the client code will look like:

```
byte[] Data = new byte[];
Type objectType;
objectType = MyFunction<Type>(Data);
```

Comment: Yeah but then the result is a Type object, this does absolutely no good, I need a object of type objectType..

Comment: Ah, I understand now what were you asking. Generics don't work with runtime determined types, they are intent to provide typesafety, which is not what you get with determining a type at runtime. Try to extract some common interface and use it with a generic method.